# Why Request method 'POST' is not supported in Java Spring v.2.2.7?

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am using Spring boot v.2.2.7 in order to implement a rest service for post http method. It work's fine from Postman but show the next error when use the browser:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).
Request method 'POST' not supported
```

My Controller:

```
@Controller
public class SystemAdministratorController {
    @Autowired
    private StyleRepository styleRepository;

    //Method get, post, put and delete for music styles
    @GetMapping("/musicalstyle")
    public String getStyle(Model model) {
        List<Style> listStyles = styleRepository.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("styles", listStyles);
        return "musicalStyle";
    }

    @PostMapping("/musicalstyle")
    public String addMusicalStyle(@Valid Style style) {
        styleRepository.save(style);
        return "template";
        }
```

Note: Get method is working fine.

My repository:

```
@Repository
public interface StyleRepository extends JpaRepository<Style, Long>{

}
```

My model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "style", schema = "musicnet")
public class Style {

    private String name;
    private String description;

    public Style() {

    }

    public Style(String name, String description) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Id
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Column(name = "description", nullable = false)
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "SystemAdministrator [name=" + name + ", description=" + description + "]";
    }
```

My web configure:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfigurationBasicAuth extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();

    }

}
```

My application

```
@SpringBootApplication() 
@EnableJpaAuditing
public class MusicnetApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MusicnetApplication.class, args);


    }

}
```

addMusicalStyle.html (form where is the call to post method):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>


</head>
<body>

    <form th:action="@{/musicalstyle}" th:object="${style}" method="post">
        <label for="name">Nombre</label>
        <input type="text" th:field="*{name}"  />
        <label for="description">Descripción</label>
        <input type="text" th:field="*{description}" />
        <button type="submit" th:text="Añadir">Añadir</button>
    </form>


</body>
</html>
```

The problem seems to be on thymeleaf. When form is submitt Spring logs show:

```
2020-05-18 20:07:45.793 DEBUG 9752 --- [nio-8182-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : POST "/addMusicalStyle.html", parameters={}
2020-05-18 20:07:45.810 DEBUG 9752 --- [nio-8182-exec-3] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler ["classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/", "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/", "/"]
2020-05-18 20:07:45.836  WARN 9752 --- [nio-8182-exec-3] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported]
2020-05-18 20:07:45.837 DEBUG 9752 --- [nio-8182-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 405 METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED
2020-05-18 20:07:45.846 DEBUG 9752 --- [nio-8182-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for POST "/error", parameters={}
2020-05-18 20:07:45.854 DEBUG 9752 --- [nio-8182-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2020-05-18 20:07:46.408 DEBUG 9752 --- [nio-8182-exec-3] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, text/html;q=0.8]
2020-05-18 20:07:46.432 DEBUG 9752 --- [nio-8182-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 405
```

Where we can see that is used: POST "/addMusicalStyle.html", parameters={}
When it should be something like: POST "/musicstyle", parameters={name="Jazz", description="From EEUU"}
So thymeleaf isn't doing his job.

My pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.musicnet</groupId>
    <artifactId>musicnet</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>musicnet</name>
    <description>MusicNet is Spring project to develop the TFG</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

It is like th:action, th:object and th:field aren't taking correct parameters (service is ok from postman client).

I have tried with Spring version 2.3.0, 2.2.7 and 2.1.14 and the result is the same.

How can I resolve it?

Thanks,

Comment: See if it works when you add `enctype='multipart/form-data'` to `<form th:action="@{/musicalstyle}" th:object="${style}" method="post">`

Comment: Checked with enctype='multipart/form-data' and still doesn't works...

Comment: Could you include the snippet of HTML produced by your template?

Comment: Try adding `@ModelAttribute` to your `@PostMapping` method parameter: `@ModelAttribute @Valid Style style`

Comment: Your code doesn't add up. You have a `Style` class with a different id type then your repository. Which all makes me wonder if this is actual code or some dumbed down version which kind-of-looks-like the real code.

Comment: @Daniel The snippet is not produced, when addMusicalStyle.html call the post method on controller, Spring server returns the error: `Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Tue May 19 15:41:51 CEST 2020
There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).
Request method 'POST' not supported`

@drumonii I put the method parameter like `@ModelAttribute @Valid Style style` but the result is the same.

@M. Deinum I change the id Long for String and the result is the same

Comment: The problem is that your Thymeleaf isn't being parsed.  The browser sees html `<form th:action="@{/musicalstyle}"` -- and since the Thymeleaf isn't being processed, it doesn't turn `th:action="@{/musicalstyle}"` into `action="/musicalstyle"` and therefore when you click the submit button it just sends the post to the same page your browser is currently on (which presumably is `addMusicalStyle.html`).  This is pretty easy to verify by right click -> view source in your browser.

Comment: @Metroids It is the exactly problem. As you say, when I view the source code is showing `th:action="@{/musicalstyle}"` so Thymeleaf isn't being parsed. How can I force to be parsed?

Comment: Where is addMusicalStyle.html in your project?

Comment: @Daniel addMusicalStyle.html is in /src/main/java/resources/static (it is not a template)

Comment: If you want "`@{/musicalstyle}`" to work in it, then it should be a template, not static.

Comment: That's correct, I have putted the addMusicalStyle.html in /src/main/java/resources/templates and now thymeleaf is processing it.

Answer (score 1):

I response me:

In order to Thymeleaf process the files them should be under /src/main/java/resources/templates so there was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you think you should use @RequestBody with @PostMapping

```
@PostMapping("/musicalstyle")
    public String addMusicalStyle(@Valid @RequestBody Style style) {
        styleRepository.save(style);
        return "template";
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

I think that the problem is totally focused on thymeleaf. I modified the addMusicalStyle.html like this:

```
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>


</head>
<body>

    <form action="/musicalstyle" method="post">
        <label for="name">Nombre</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" />
        <label for="description">Descripción</label>
        <input type="text" name="description" />
        <button type="submit">Añadir</button>
    </form>


</body>
</html>
```

And template is returned as a normal so there is something wrong with the th fields.

In additional, I can see thymeleaf classes on Eclipse menu Navigate -> Open type... -> Find Thymeleaf